# iOS UICollectionView: How to show there's hidden cells

Tags: ios, hidden

I have a UICollectionView, which I have set to having a single row and then the user can scroll horizontally to see any cells that aren't visible on the screen (to save space).

What is the best way to show that the user should scroll in order to see more cells? Is a simple arrow okay for this? As I would think the user would try and simply press the arrow rather than it be an indication to scroll.

Comment: Have you got a mockup / screenshot of how this looks currently?

Comment: I've been trying to achieve what micap said below "3.5 tiles can be shown with the 4th tile partially visible". Unforunately in a UITableView/UICollectionView, partially visible cells doesn't show at all unless scrolled upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways that you can indicate to the user that they can scroll horizontally.

If you have a collection view of tiles you can design the app so that the tile dimensions don't fit completely in the frame. e.g. 3.5 tiles can be shown with the 4th tile partially visible.

Another option is to display page/scroll indicators at the bottom of the app.

In one app we've also animated the scrolling, but I'd only do this once.

Answer (score 1):

You could do what some Android phones do to indicate the drop down menu can be scrolled.

Display the control already scrolled partially and slowly scroll it back to the start.

(trying to find an example but drawing a blank)

Comment: No worries, I understand what you mean. Thanks for the suggestion!